# std::views:filter for some reason can't deduce argument type in a function pointer

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I was learning how to use std::ranges and decided to experiment with c++23 std::views::enumerate and wrote something like this:

```
using namespace std;
auto isnt_nullptr(auto t) {
    return get<1>(t) != nullptr;
}


int main() {
    int i1 = 1, i2 = 3, i4 = 8;
    int* ptrs[5]{nullptr, &i1, &i2, nullptr, &i4};
    for (auto [index, ptr] : ptrs | views::enumerate 
                                  | views::filter(isnt_nullptr)) {
        puts(format("{}: {}", index, *ptr).c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and it spat out usual error gibberish

> error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::views::_Filter) (<unresolved overloaded function type>)'

By the way I was doing this in a compiler explorer using gcc (trunk) with -std=c++23 flag, no other flags were applied

I thought that maybe for some reason compiler couldn't deduce function argument so I explicitly wrote: `auto isnt_nullptr(tuple<long int, int*> t)` and it worked. I thought that it is too bothersome to specify a type every time and tried using lambda instead without much hope.
So I used this instead of a function pointer:

```
for (auto [index, ptr] : ptrs | views::enumerate 
                              | views::filter([](auto pair){
                                    return get<1>(pair) != nullptr;
                                })
    ) {
    puts(format("{}: {}", index, *ptr).c_str());
}
```

and it worked, after that I wrapped my function, which accepted auto as an argument, in the lambda:
`[](auto t){ return isnt_nullptr(t); }`
and it worked as well and I have no clue why.
Can someone please explain why function pointer is a no-no in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isnt_nullptr` is not a function. It is a function template. Therefore you can't have a function pointer to it, only to one of its specializations.

When passing `isnt_nullptr` to `views::filter`, `views::filter` takes its argument as a generic type, so there is no target type that could be used to deduce which specialization of `isnt_nullptr` you want to pass. Therefore the error mentioning that the overload set for `isnt_nullptr` couldn't be resolved to a single function.

You can state explicitly which specialization you want to pass with `views::filter(isnt_nullptr<tuple<long int, int*>>)` or you can use the lambda approach you showed.

The lambda approach works because you are not passing a function at all in that case. You are instead passing the lambda object, which has its `operator()` called inside `views::filter`. Overload resolution to a specific specialization of the templated `operator()` will happen at that call site.